# Show ASPxPopup control which is on another page

Tags: asp.net, .net, devexpress

I have a DevExpress ASPxPopup control on a page. Now I want to show that popup when I click the link on the menu bar which is in master page.

I can access popup in master page using Master.FindControl() but I don't know how to access popup in a child page.

Comment: Why don't you contact the DX guys regarding your issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that When page is completely loaded then Master page and child aspx page rendered html markup and script are available to work with it. So you can access both popupControls on either Master page or ChildPage.

Just Assign Set [ASPxPopupControl.ClientInstanceName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPopupControlASPxPopupControlBase_ClientInstanceNametopic) and use button's clientside event to show or hide the popup.

Check the following working example:
//Master page markup

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="parentPopupControl" ClientInstanceName="parentPopup" runat="server">
            <ContentCollection>
<dx:PopupControlContentControl runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">this 
    is parent popup</dx:PopupControlContentControl>
</ContentCollection>
        </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
        <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="hlnkShowChildPopup" runat="server" Text="Show Child Popup">
            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
    childPopup.Show();
}" />
        </dx:ASPxHyperLink>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>`
```

///Child Page Markup

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="childPopupControl" runat="server" 
    ClientInstanceName="childPopup">
    <ContentCollection>
<dx:PopupControlContentControl runat="server" SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">this 
    is child popup control</dx:PopupControlContentControl>
</ContentCollection>
</dx:ASPxPopupControl>

    <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="hlnkShowParentPopup" runat="server" Text="Show Parent Popup">
            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
    parentPopup.Show();
}" />
        </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
</asp:Content>`
```

Note: You can't consume popup control in better way with server side includes, so take a learning on callbacks and callbackpanel etc to work client side scripts.

Hope this help you..

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this on client side. Set [ASPxPopupControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxPopupControlASPxPopupControltopic).[ClientInstanceName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPopupControlASPxPopupControlBase_ClientInstanceNametopic). Then use popup contorl [client side methods](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPopupControlScriptsASPxClientPopupControlMembersTopicAll) like Show or ShowWindow.